# Download sqlite database from URL

Tags: objective-c

I'm using this code the load the local sqlite database.

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"sqlite3"];
        _db = [[MDDatabase alloc] initWithPath:path];
        _HTMLRenderer = [[MDHTMLRenderer alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I would like to put the database online and let the app download the database instead. I changed the code to:

```
NSData *dbFile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.com/DatabaseName.sqlite"]];

        NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

        NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sqlite"];

        [dbFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        _db = [[MDDatabase alloc] initWithPath:filePath];
        _HTMLRenderer = [[MDHTMLRenderer alloc] init];
```

Editted:
I changed my code to follow but it's crashed.

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downalod) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
        NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

        NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sqlite"];
        _db = [[MDDatabase alloc] initWithPath:filePath];
        _HTMLRenderer = [[MDHTMLRenderer alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)download
{

    NSData *dbFile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.com/DatabaseName.sqlite"]];

    NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

    NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sqlite"];

    [dbFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: There are countless examples for correctly getting a reference to the Documents folder. Please search on `NSDocumentDirectory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time search, finally I solved it myself:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSData *fetchedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.com/db.sqlite3"]];
        NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite3"];
        [fetchedData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        _db = [[MDDatabase alloc] initWithPath:filePath];
        _HTMLRenderer = [[MDHTMLRenderer alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have problem in your file. Check with correct url. Its an encoding issue. Try with this (It will work) : http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/apollo/apollo17/hires/s72-55482.jpg
2. Add App Transport Security Settings (Allow Arbitrary Loads YES) in your plist.
3. Enable background mode.
4. Declare this macro in .m

   ```
   #define DocumentsDirectory [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]
   ```

Now call and you will have the file in your local.

Call like:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downalod) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

  _db = [[MDDatabase alloc] initWithPath:filePath];
    _HTMLRenderer = [[MDHTMLRenderer alloc] init];

 -(void)download
 {

    NSString *stringURL =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"url"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

NSString *filePath = [DocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[url lastPathComponent]];
NSLog(@"success--222,%@", filePath);

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{

    NSLog(@"success--222,%@", filePath);


    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"success--not---Error,%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"success--yes... %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);

        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    }
}];
 }
```

Comment: Where should I put the `self performSelectorOnMainThread` code? Is it under `- (id)init`?

Comment: Yes. let me know.

Comment: I dont know who downvote it. Explain the cause of your down-voting.@someone.

Comment: The app crashed. Can you help to see whether the code is correct?

Comment: Give me your url. let me try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126380/discussion-between-user2872856-and-jamshed-alam).

Comment: I also have tried with AFNETWORKING. It says: UserinfoDataRequest-- receivedString for failure: ( so, check your file on server.